# C# not capturing a methods return value still requires a reference to the returned type

Tags: c#

I have two DLLs and my application. My application references DLL1 and DLL1 references DLL2, like so:

Application -> DLL1 -> DLL2.

DLL1 contains a method that returns a type in DLL2. This method is not usable in my application because my application does not have a reference to DLL2. Here is my code:

```
// My Application
DLL1.DoSomething(""); <-- The type 'MyType' is defined in an assembly that is not references.

// DLL1
public static MyType DoSomething(string x);

// DLL2
public class MyType;
```

I could understand this if I was capturing the output of `DLL1.DoSomething`, but as in this example, I do not care about the output. (I use it elsewhere in DLL2). Is there any way for me to avoid the reference error?

Comment: Why do you care? You´ll need the assembly anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is capturing the returned result, it's just immediately throwing it away.  The compiler isn't terribly concerned with what you *do* with the result, if anything at all.  But in order to understand that method call *at all*, all types related to it must be known.

You can obscure types used *within* the method, but any types advertised by the method signature must be known to any code which invokes that method.

Comment: I don't think the compiler needs to know the type to generate the CIL (AFAIK `void` is the only one requiring special treatment). But of course it's convenient for the compiler writer to assume knowledge of all relevant types.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You mixed theory with implementation. Your first sentence is theory, and the second one is assumed implementation. For most of us, experts, there is no problem in understanding what you mean, but if your comment is to be read and understood by all readers, you probably should've made it clearer the separation between the two :).

Answer (score 2):

Not using regular C# - you need access to the return type to resolve the method. You could perhaps invoke it with reflection or via `dynamic` (if it is an instance method), but adding the missing reference would be easier. It'll be needed at runtime *anyway*, so you don't lose anything by adding a reference.